# Performing a blocking request in django view

Tags: python, django, celery

In one of the views in my django application, I need to perform a relatively lengthy network IO operation. The problem is other requests must wait for this request to be completed even though they have nothing to do with it.
I did some research and stumbled upon Celery but as I understand, it is used to perform background tasks independent of the request. (so I can not use the result of the task for the response to the request)

Is there a way to process views asynchronously in django so while the network request is pending other requests can be processed?

Edit: What I forgot to mention is that my application is a web service using django rest framework. So the result of a view is a json response not a page that I can later modify using AJAX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store the result of a delay-call using celery in a django view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703472/how-to-store-the-result-of-a-delay-call-using-celery-in-a-django-view)

Comment: @Louis Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Refer to the edit.

Comment: And the solution remains the same.

Comment: please elaborate on your stack...  Are you using uwsgi, gunicorn, or just `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @Louis If we do that, we are moving unnecessary complexity which should be taken care of on the server side to the client application. Although it is certainly a solution, it is not an elegant one.

Comment: @TimTisdall For now i'm just using runserver but for deployment i will probably use uwsgi.

Comment: @alimostafavi - it kind of depends on how long is "relatively lengthy".  :)  If it's over a minute I'd say moving it over to the client isn't unreasonable because it's likely clients will timeout the connection any way.  If it's 10 seconds, then yeah, do it on the server.

Comment: @alimostafavi - well, there's your problem...  I don't think 'runserver' can handle more than one request at a time.  You need to move to something that can handle multiple requests at a time.  uwsgi can be used to have one process per cpu core and then 1000 green threads per process.

Comment: @TimTisdall By relatively lengthy, I mean around 2 seconds. Although it is not much, when every request blocks for that amount of time, it will add up quickly. Thanks for the other comment, I will definitely check out uwsgi.

Comment: @alimostafavi - for 2 seconds, definitely handle it on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution here is to offload the task to celery, and return a "please wait" response in your view. If you want, you can then use an Ajax call to periodically hit a view that will report whether the response is ready, and redirect when it is.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that my application is a web service using django rest framework. So the result of a view is a json response not a page that I can later modify using javascript.

Comment: @alimostafavi It'd be possible to have one REST call initiate the process and return a task id and then have a different request ask for the result of that task and either return the end result or a "not ready yet".

Answer (score 0):

You want to maintain that HTTP connection for an extended period of time but still allow other requests to be managed, right?  There's no simple solution to this problem.  Also, any solution will be a level away from Django as it depends on how you process requests.

I don't know what you're currently using, so I can only tell you how I handled this in the past...  I was using uwsgi to provide the WSGI interface between my python application and nginx.  In uwsgi I used the [asynchronous functions](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonModule.html#async-functions) to suspend my long running connection when there was time to wait on the IO connections.  The methods allow you to ask it to suspend things until there is something to read or write and then allow other connections to be serviced.

The above mentioned async calls use "green threads".  It's much lighter weight then regular threads and you have control over when you move from thread to thread.

Answer (score -1):

I am not saying that it is a good solution for your scenario[1], but the simple answer is using the following pattern:

```
async_result = some_task.delay(arg1)
result = async_result.get()
```

Check documentation for the [`get` method](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get). And instead of using the `delay` method you can use anything that returns an AsyncResult (like the [`apply_async` method](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async)

---

[1] Why it may be a bad idea? Having an ongoing connection waiting a lot is bad for Django (it is not ready for long-lived connections), may conflict with the proxy configuration (if there is a reverse proxy somewhere) and may be identified as a timeout from the browser. So... it seems a Bad Idea[TM] to use this pattern for a Django Rest Framework view.

Comment: How is this different from just performing the blocking request? Doesn't get() block anyway?

Comment: If the worker is away, the `get()` should release the GIL. This means that the Python code should be unblocked. You cannot release the connection and expect to answer it from Django, but you can "outsource" the task and patiently wait for it while the interpreter is working in other things.

Comment: @alimostafavi However, don't use the `runserver` to really check the behaviour. It should never be used in production and it is not ready to handle anything serious. You should use something like uwsgi, gunicorn... and then you can check if you really need to use some pattern.